# Transform selector to UUID array

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I need to add vanilla selectors (as `@a` or `@p`, but I also want to add there selector arguments as `@a[team=blue]`) to my plugin command. Is there some library or even some build-in function in bukkit? I tried executing command, that returns UUID or name, but I had problem with reading its result.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you want, but if you want to return Players UUID just do it like that:

```
player.getUniqueID();
```

and thats it. You can return this to a player by making a command and sending him a message with:

```
player.sendMessage(player.getUniqueID.toString());
```